# HttpPost addHeader doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I downloaded the HttpComponents library from apache.org and I've added the httpclient-4.3.5.jar to the libraries in my project in Eclipse. Now I'm trying to add a header to my HttpPost but Eclipse does not find the function "addHeader()".

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(PUSH_URL);
post.addHeader("test", "tmp");
```

I've tried different libraries but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right classes in your project.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well I did import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; do i need other imports aswell?

Comment: And does Eclipse show you on error on the `import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost` line? (Could it actually import it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addHeader` method in HttpPost is extended from `org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage`,and the `AbstractHttpMessage` is in the `httpcore-version.jar`.Therefore, you have to add other jar library.
For safely use, you can add those in the build path:
[image]

Comment: oh, thank you very much! I wonder why i didnt think about adding the other libraries aswell. Works!